# Communicate between component via service observable fail

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I want to create log-in form, when login successfully, the root component receive data then display it. I created login service and root component could receive notification with subscribe() method, but it seems not work.
here is my code:

```
//app.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { HttpConstant } from './constants/http.response';
import { LoginService } from './services/login.service';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
    providers: [LoginService]
})

export class AppComponent {
  currentUser = 'Anonymous';

  constructor(private loginService: LoginService) {
      console.log(loginService);
      loginService.logInAnnouncement$.subscribe(email => {
          console.log(email);
          this.currentUser = email;
      });
  }
}
//login.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';

import { Profile } from '../entities/profile';
import { GuardService } from './guard.service';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {

    private headers = new Headers();
    private loginUrl = 'api/v1/auth/login';
    private email = new Subject<string>();

    /**
    * Observable string streams
    */
    logInAnnouncement$ = this.email.asObservable();

    constructor(private http: Http, private guard: GuardService) {
    }

    login(email, password): Observable<any> {
        this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        this.headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
        return this.http
          .post(this.loginUrl, JSON.stringify({email: email, password: password}), {headers: this.headers})
          .map((res:Response) => res.json());
    }

    announceLogIn(email: string) {
        this.email.next(email);
        this.logInAnnouncement$.subscribe(email=>{
            console.log(email);
        });
        console.log('OK');
    }
}
//login.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { LoginService } from '../services/login.service';
import { Profile } from '../entities/profile';
import { HttpConstant } from '../constants/http.response';


@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'fix-login',
    templateUrl: 'login.component.html',
    providers: [LoginService, HttpConstant],
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

    profile: Profile;
    validatingHandler: ValidateError;
    // profile: Profile;

    constructor(private loginService: LoginService,
                 private router: Router) { 
        this.profile = new Profile();
        this.validatingHandler = new ValidateError();
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {

    }

    doLogin(event): void {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.loginService.login(this.profile.email, this.profile.password)
            .subscribe((data: Object) => {
                if (data.status == 0) {
                    this.loginService.announceLogIn(this.profile.email);
                    this.router.navigate(['/']);
                }
            }, err => { 

                if (err.status == HttpConstant.HTTP_INVALID_INPUT ) {
                    this.validatingError(err.json());
                }
            })

    }

    private validatingError(error): void {
        this.validatingHandler = new ValidateError();
        this.validatingHandler._email = error.email;
        this.validatingHandler._password = error.password;
    }


}

class ValidateError {
    _email: string;
    _password: string;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't add `LoginService` to `providers` of every component. This way every component will get its own instance injected.

Add it to providers of `@NgModule()` instead, this way all components will get the same instance injected.

Comment: You're welcome. DI starts searching for providers from the component that has a dependency (constructor parameter) and continues at it's parents until it finds a matching provider. DI maintains single instances per provider. If you add providers to `@NgModule()` then they are added to the root injector which are shared with the whole application.

Comment: You can also define providers for subtrees of your application by adding them to components. For smaller applications using the root injector is usually safe, for larger applications or more specific use cases you might want more fine grained control by adding providers to components.

Comment: Should I separate @ngModule into many pieces or just keep using one at the root of application?

Comment: I'd say combine components, directives, pipes, services into modules at the "level of reuse". That's usually one module per feature. If you want to use a specific feature, you should just have to add one module to `imports` of your current `@NgModule()`. For small apps one `@NgModule()` might do, but for larger apps you usually want to create a hierarchie of modules where you have modules for smaller features and modules that combine smaller features to more complex features.

Comment: Thanks Günter, you rescued me out of many hours of anger and desperation!! :-)

Comment: Glad to hear, that's what SO is supposed to do, isn't it :-)